# xcode build legacy project, having error "You are not permitted to create distribution provisioning profiles for team"

Tags: ios, xcode10.1

When using xcode 10.1 to build a legacy project to generate IPA file to upload to AppleStore. I added the parameter of '-UseModernBuildSystem=NO" to make sure it using 'Legacy Build' system.

After Apple change the role/permission policy last month, i get this error:
You are not permitted to create distribution provisioning profiles for team.  Please contact one of your team admins, who can create a profile on your behalf.

In the Apple's new role/permission, i'm not in the "Account Holder" role. What can i do beside using he 'Account Holder' role to generate the IPA file?

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same issue a couple of days after the recent roles changes. While I was granted all the necessary rights at appstoreconnect.apple.com, there seemed to be a bug in appstore. The bug in question prevented me from creating/editing distribution profiles in developer.apple.com, it showed me the "You are not permitted to create distribution provisioning profiles for team. Please contact one of your team admins, who can create a profile on your behalf." error.

I've managed to solve the problem by having the account holder do the following steps:

1. go to appstoreconnect.apple.com -> "Users and Access"
2. click invited_user@email.com (the account holder will observe the already enabled "App Manager" and "Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.")
3. remove "App Manager" and even "Developer" Roles (the "Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles." will be disabled automatically, once "Developer" is disabled)
4. Save
5. add back the "App Manager" role and "Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles." in Developer Resources
6. once again Save

Hope this helps you too (if you're "Developer", not "App Manager", it should work just the same, I believe you just need the account holder to remove your rights and then add them again).

Comment: I think this should fix.
I try another way - add the 'Admin' role beside 'App Manger' role to fix it.

Comment: Hi @Jack ! Eventually adding `Admin` role has solved the issue?

Comment: I didn't set `Admin`, but resetting and setting up again roles did the trick! Pay attention that Apple takes up to 10 minutes to synch roles...